# Showing a function of 2 variables is differentiable over ${R^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am self studying multivariable calculus and I want to know how to show that $f(x,y) = {x^2} + {y^2}$ is differentiable. At least that is the first example from my book, if you know a more illustrative example that would be fine.

In single variable calculus, I would just use the definition and show the limit exists but I don't know the definition in two variables and I'm not sure if that applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In single variable calculus, I would just use the definition and show the limit exists but I don't know the definition in two variables and I'm not sure if that applies.

Calculate $\nabla f(x,y)$ and show that it is continous, $\Rightarrow$ differentiable.

$$
\nabla f(x,y) = (2x,2y)
$$
We want to show that 
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} \nabla f(x,y) = \nabla f(a,b)
$$
The usual things we do when calculating limits is that we try to calculate the value $f(a,b)$, if this is definied (no troubles for example $0/0$) then we conclude that the limit while approaching $(a,b)$ is equal to $f(a,b)$

Since $\nabla f(x,y) = (2x, 2y)$ will never get us into "trouble" for any $x,y$ then we conclude that

$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b) \nabla f(x,y)} = f(a,b)
$$
Thus, continous.

Comment: I can calculate the gradient but how do I show it's continuous everywhere?

Comment: Which defintion of continouity are you familiar with? epsilon, delta and/or  with limits?

Comment: Definition with limits.

Comment: Chech my edit @Hans

Answer (score 1):

Function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by definition is differentiable at a point $(a, b)$ if there is a linear function $L : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that

$$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{\\||f(a+h, b+k)-f(a,b) - L(h,k)\|}{\\||(h,k)\|}=0$$

And a theorem states that if that is so, then such $L$ must be unique and in fact is given by $L(h,k) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a, b),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a, b)\right) \cdot (h, k)$.

For your $f$, the partials are $2x$ and $2y$, respectively. Now compute the quotient in the right-hand side of the displayed formula and see that it has limit $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ if $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(a,b)-f_x(a,b)(x-a)-f_y(a,b)(y-b)}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}=0$$ where $f_x$ and $f_y$ are the partial derivatives.